# Analytical expression for the Logistic function mirrored in diagonal plane?

Tags: probability-distributions, regression

I want to fit some data which is a normalised cumulative histogram which looks like so:

[image]

I was thinking that to fit this S shaped cumulative distribution I wanted a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)  but if I attempt this I get the following:

[image]

This is with the expression $$ f(x) = \dfrac{L}{1 + e^{-k(x-x_0)}} $$ where $L = 1$, $k = 0.02$ and $x_0$ = 0.

I therefore need the mirror of the logistic function in the diagonal plane, is there an analytical function which is the diagonal mirror of the logistic function or do I need to mirror the logistic function using a geometric transformation?

### Edit with solution:

caverac's answer below was the correct solution with the modification he proposed in the comments:

$$
g(x) = -a\log\left(\frac{k}{(x+c)} - 1\right) + b
$$

with the following values:

- $a = 0.2$
- $b = 0.5$
- $c = 300$
- $k = 600$

This produces the following plot:

[image]

Where the red line is the equation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invert your relation you can get the "diagonal reflection" you're looking for

$$
g(x) = -a\log\left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right) + b
$$

Comment: How do I use this when my x is greater than 1 as it is in the case above? Since log of a negative number is not defined?

Comment: If I try to divide x by 1000 such that x is less than 1 I also do not get the shape I required, the 'diagonal mirror' of the logistic function.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist Change $x\to k(x - c)$

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist Try $x \to \frac{x-300}{600}$ with $-300 < x < 300$, that should give you the plot you have

Comment: I've tried $$ -1 log(\dfrac{600}{x-300} - 1) + 0 $$ and I just get NaNs

Comment: I needed to do $$ -1 log(\dfrac{600}{x+300} - 1) + 0 $$ instead, just a sign mistake.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist Great! Yup, it was a typo, my bad